# Scala Serializing a Seq of Objects or Any

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I ran into a problem with serializing a model: 
MyModel:

```
case class DocumentModel(
                          documentId: Option[Int] = None,
                          title: String,
                          ...
                          responsibleList: Option[Seq[UserModel]], // No problem
                          preConditions: Option[Seq[Object]], // Problem occurs here
                          postConditions: Option[Seq[Object]] // Problem occurs here
                        )

object DocumentModel {
  implicit val documentFormat = Jsonx.formatCaseClass[DocumentModel]
}
```

`responsibleList`, `preConditions` as well as `postConditions` are not stored in the database, they only serve as helper lists. I proceed to fill those lists in my controller in order to send it back to the front-end via `JSON`:

```
val document = for {
  newDocument <- documentDTO.getDocument(documentId, clientId)
  responsibleList <- raciDocumentDTO.getResponsible_Documents(documentId)
  ...
  preConditions <- conditionController.getPreConditions(documentId)
  postConditions <- conditionController.getPostConditions(documentId)
} yield (newDocument, responsibleList, ..., preConditions, postConditions)

document.map({ case (newDocument, responsibleList, ..., preConditions, postConditions) =>
  val temp = newDocument.map(docu => {
    ...

    val doc = new DocumentModel(
      docu.documentId,
      docu.title,
      ...
      Some(responsibleList),
      Some(preConditions),
      Some(postConditions)
    )
    doc
  })

  Ok(Json.obj(
    "document" -> temp,
  ))
})
```

I suspect it has something to do with `Option[Seq[Object]]` or `Option[Seq[Any]]` for that matter. The compiler throws an error: 
[image]
Since `preConditions` and `postConditions` can be `instances/objects` from various `models`, I can't explicitly state which model it should be. Is there a solution to this problem or do I have to take another path?
Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

I added:

```
trait Condition

object Condition {
  import play.api.libs.json._

  implicit val conditionWrites: Writes[Condition] = Writes[Condition] {
    case a: DocumentModel => JsObject(Seq("DocumentModel" -> Jsonx(a)))
    case b: ProcessModel => JsObject(Seq("ProcessModel" -> Jsonx(b)))
    case c: ProcessInstanceModel => JsObject(Seq("ProcessInstanceModel" -> Jsonx(c)))
  }
}
```

And in my models:

```
case class DocumentModel(
                          documentId: Option[Int] = None,
                          title: String,
                          ...,
                          responsibleList: Option[Seq[UserModel]],
                          preConditions: Option[Seq[Condition]],
                          postConditions: Option[Seq[Condition]]
                        ) extends Condition
```

It still leaves me with this error message:

[image]

[image]

That's the first time I ran into such a problem and I'm honestly a little bit confused.

**Update 2**

I've tried it like you mentioned, but It still throws the same error.

My code looks like this:

[image]

**UPDATE**

I implemented the suggested changes and I narrowed the problem down to this:

```
trait Condition

object Condition {
  implicit val conditionWrites: Writes[Condition] = Writes[Condition] {
    case a: DocumentModel => JsObject(Seq(
      "documentId" -> Json.toJson(a.documentId),
      "title" -> Json.toJson(a.title),
       ...
      "responsibleList" -> Json.toJson(a.responsibleList),
      "preConditions" -> Json.toJson(a.preConditions),
      "postConditions" -> Json.toJson(a.postConditions)
    ))
    case b: ...
  }

}
```

When I do it like this, I get the following error message:

[image]
So I figured that an `implicit read` might be missing. So I added:

```
object Condition {
  implicit val conditionReads: OFormat[Condition] = Json.format[Condition] // New

  implicit val conditionWrites: Writes[Condition] = Writes[Condition] {
    case a: DocumentModel => JsObject(Seq(
      "documentId" -> Json.toJson(a.documentId),
      "title" -> Json.toJson(a.title),
      ...
```

However, when running the code I get this:

```
    No unapply or unapplySeq function found
    [error]   implicit val conditionReads: OFormat[Condition] = Json.format[Condition]
```

A suggested solution to fix this was to change my `object condition` to `case class condition`. However, this would destroy the entire purpose of creating such a generic `trait/object`.

Comment: What is `Object`? What is its contents and structure?

Comment: Maybe object is wrong. I also tried `ANY`. And got the same error

I want to pass a seq of various types.

Comment: You cannot have `Any` because its structure is not known . Any can be anything. Try to narrow down your type

Comment: I want to assign different models to the seq

Comment: You can probably create a trait AnOutput and declare the objects to be of type AnOutput

Comment: It's far from being recommended to use `Any` or `Object`, moreover if you need to resolve typeclass instances (there JSON encoding) appropriately according the value types (basically it more seems to be a design issue).

Comment: @esardes do you have an example for me?

Comment: @cchantep I want to make it as generic as possible

Comment: `Any` is not generic, it's "just" untyped/unknown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have all your "condition" models extend a trait that that has a JSON writable. For example,

```
trait Condition

object Condition {

  implicit val conditionWrites: Writes[Condition] = Writes[Condition] {
    case a: PreConditionA => JsObject(Seq("field" -> JsString(a.stringValue))) //or whatever
    case b: PreConditionB => //...
    //etc...
    case x: PostConditionX => //...
    case y: PostConditionY => //...
    //etc...
  }

}

case class PreConditionA(stringValue: String) extends Condition
//etc.
```

Then in `DocumentModel`, change the conditions' types to the `Condition` trait:

```
case class DocumentModel(
  documentId: Option[Int] = None,
  title: String,
  //...
  responsibleList: Option[Seq[UserModel]], 
  preConditions: Option[Seq[Condition]], 
  postConditions: Option[Seq[Condition]]
)
```

You may have to convert the serialization syntax to whatever it is for Jsonx, but hopefully it's similar enough and you get the idea.

Comment: thanks, I tried Id but have some issues. I've updated my question above

Comment: @Felix Your pre- and post-condition models, instead of being `Objects` (the Java equivalent of Scala's `Any`) would need to be explicit and extend the `Condition` trait. For example, `case class PreConditionA(stringValue: String) extends Condition`. You can't just serialize any `Object` or `Any` to JSON, because Jsonx won't know its makeup. You'd need to explicitly define your models.

Comment: @Felix so as you have it written above, you're saying `DocumentModel`, `ProcessModel` and `ProcessInstanceModel` are conditions that are the objects in the `preConditions` and `postConditions` sequences. I'm not sure this correct, because `DocumentModel` is what also holds these conditions sequences. But assuming it is, then you would do `case class DocumentModel(...) extends Condition`, `case class ProcessModel(...) extends Condition`, etc., then in your writable `case d: DocumentModel => JsObject(Seq("title" -> JsString(d.title), ...))`, same for `ProcessModel`, etc.

Comment: @Felix You should not change `condition` to a case class, nor could you. *If* you need a `Reads` for the `Condition` trait, then you will have to create it manually, just like you did with writes. However, the problem does not seem to be with the lack of a `Reads`. We need to focus on the lack of implicit for `tjs`, but I don't see `tjs` in the code you've pasted above. What is `tjs`? Perhaps you can post a more explicit error message instead of the IntelliJ screenshot.

Comment: what is tjs? Can you maybe make a working example for me?

Comment: @Felix Your error message says "No implicits found for parameter tjs". I have no idea what it is.